# Is there any way to redirecting to another alive node(in this situation B,C) in cluster automatically when host A(master) is dead?

Tags: arangodb

In order to cluster host A(master), B, C on each different machine.

To cluster 3 machine in daemon, I executed 3 commands below

On host A
`nohup arangodb --starter.data-dir=/mypath/arangodb/ &`

On host B
`nohup arangodb --starter.join A(ip adress for A) --starter.data-dir=/mypath/arangodb/ &`

On host C
`nohup arangodb --starter.join A(ip adress for A) --starter.data-dir=/mypath/arangodb/ &`

And I got 3 coordinators(port:8529), 3 db servers(port:8530) and 3 agents(port:8531) then clustered successfully.

And I use java client for basic CRUD to cluster.
`ArangoDB arangoDB = new ArangoDB.Builder().host(hostA, PORT).build();`
hostA: host of A(master), PORT: 8529

I have a question about this!

If host A(master) dead, any request to host A is blocked and connection refused.

Is there any way to redirecting to another alive node(in this situation B,C) in cluster automatically when host A is dead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ArangoDB Java driver supports fallback for hosts since version `4.1.10`. Simply use the method `host(String, int)` multiple times for every of your coordinators.

As soon as the driver lost connection to hostA it tries to connect to hostB and so on. Only after every host isn't reachable anymore an exception is thrown.

```
ArangoDB arangoDB = new ArangoDB.Builder()
  .host(hostA, PORTA)
  .host(hostB, PORTB)
  .host(hostC, PORTC)
  .build();
```